# invalid literal error when coverting from Hexadecimal colour codes to RGB

Tags: python, hex, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am trying to run some code that converts a hexadecimal colour code to RGB values in python.

This is my function for it:

```
def hex_to_rgb(value):
    value = value.lstrip('#')
    lv = len(value)
    return tuple(int(value[i:i+lv//3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv//3))
```

And when I run it I get this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 16: '<'
  File "/Users/leogaunt/Documents/Programming/Compression/Program.py", line 10, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(int(value[i:i+lv//3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv//3))
  File "/Users/leogaunt/Documents/Programming/Compression/Program.py", line 10, in hex_to_rgb
    return tuple(int(value[i:i+lv//3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv//3))
  File "/Users/leogaunt/Documents/Programming/Compression/Program.py", line 46, in <module>
    rgbList[x] = hex_to_rgb(hexArray[x])
```

On line 45 and 46 I have a loop that converts the Hexadecimal codes to RGB codes using the earlier function:

```
for x in range(0,len(hexArray)):
        rgbList[x] = hex_to_rgb(hexArray[x])
```

Is this a problem with the `rgbList` array?

The data I am using is imported from a file and is separated by dots into an array, the data looks like this:

```
82afe8.82afe6.82b0e4.
```

And then is split up into an array using

```
hexArray = str(pixelFile).split(".")
```

Comment: When I test your `hex_to_rgb` function with `'#FF0033'` I get `(255, 0, 51)` as expected. When I test it with `'#FF0033<'` I get the same error you do. The problem seems to be in the source of your input data, which you haven't provided but I'm guessing has a regex that's grabbing one extraneous character after the desired string, possibly the opening of an HTML tag.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have attached the data and where I get it from.

Comment: And then `hexArray` is what, exactly?

Comment: `hexArray` is the an array where all the hex values are stored like `[82afe8,82afe6,2b0e4]`

Comment: Well, one of those hex values has the `'<'` character in there with it. I suggest you double-check.